# Source paths being preserved in Stacktrace in release build after .NET 6 upgrade

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

We have recently upgraded our C# application from .NET Core 3.0 to .NET 6 and we are seeing an issue where our error logs have source path in the errors (the path has build machine information).

We are using the following commands in CMD to build and publish the application:

```
@SET _config=%1
@IF '%_config%'=='' (SET _config=Release)
dotnet build ..\name.sln -c:%_config% -v:minimal
    @IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (GOTO lbl_error)
    
dotnet test ..\source\name.Tests
@IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (GOTO lbl_error)

dotnet publish ..\source\namecore\name.csproj -c:%_config% --self-contained:true -r:win-x64 -f:net6.0 -p:PublishTrimmed=true -o:..\source\name\bin\Release\Publish\
@IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (GOTO lbl_error)
```

I have read that these settings are preserved if we are building in debug mode but this isn't the case here. Have been ripping my hair out for this error but can't figure it out.

Any help will be appreciated, if I have missed any info please let me know.

Comment: isn't the fact that you have a pdb the reason you get source paths in exception traces? If you don't ship your pdb (aka remove it form the publish but keep it at your builld site) do you still get these paths in logging?

Comment: @rene I do have pdbs in the release folder but shouldn't doing a release build and release publish not create these pdbs? Also,for our .net core 3.1 application we also shipped these pdb files but it didn't show the source paths in exception traces.

Comment: @rene not carrrying the pdb files to the deployment machine does work for the logging issue. No longer seeing the source paths, but it would be nice to know if this change was something that wasn't present in .net core 3.1. Any idea about why we wouldn't see it in .net CORE 3.1 and seeing in .NET 6.

Comment: There has been some changes to have a pdb format that can be used cross-platform but I don't have details on where and how these changes came into effect and how they changed the compile results between versions of the compiler/sdk.

Comment: @rene would you like to post an answer so that future visitors can be aware? it'll be highly appreciated!

Comment: It used to be possible to create a PDB with the source and line number removed.  But that capability [was lost](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/25550#issuecomment-374996117).  In other words, you deployed PDBs with that info before, but just never noticed.  Possibly because CoreCLR could not yet read the portable format in 3.1.  Well, not much you can do but turn PDB generation off completely (DebugType property) or just not deploy them.  Nothing lost.